# Real Analysis limit

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis

Well, let $f:\Bbb R\to \Bbb R $ a Riemann integrable function in $[0,2\pi]$, $2\pi$ periodic.
I must prove that $$\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac {1}{2\pi} \int_{0}^{2\pi} f(x)g(nx)dx=\frac {1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi}f(x)dx\frac {1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi}g(x)dx$$

What I've done so far is the following steps:

I have proved it for the $\sin(kx),\cos(mx)$ functions, where $k,n \in \mathbb{Z}$. Then I proved it for every trigonometric function and then for every continuous function using the fact that  for every continuous function there is a sequence of trigonometric functions that converge uniformly to the continuous function.

Then the last step is that for every integrable function let say $f$ there is a sequence of continuous functions, $f_n$ such that $\|f_n-f\|_1\to 0$.

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

Write $f(x)$ as a Fourier series, that is:
$$\frac{c_0}{2}+\sum_{k=1}^\infty c_k\cos(kx)+s_k\sin(kx)$$
where $s_k,c_k$ are appropriate real numbers. This equals $f(x)$ almost everywhere, thus you can put it in the integral instead of $f(x)$, then you have to motivate why you can interchange the summation and the integral. When you have done that, you can use what you have already proven to conclude.

Comment: Shouldn't it be $\cos(kx)$ and $\sin(kx)$ ?

Comment: You mean that i have to use measure theory "almost everywhere".Also in order to interchange the summation and the integral we must have uniform convergance that we don't have. So,if you mean something else please tell me.Thank you!

Comment: @ThomasProduit Corrected, thank you.

Comment: @user113576 You need a.e. because if the function is e.g. not continuous, then the Fourier series will not necessarily give you exactly the original function, but a.e. is enough because you are integrating. Also I would rather use the dominated convergence theorem to show you can interchange summation and integral (using the fact that $[0,2\pi]$ is compact and a couple basic facts about Fourier series).